# mat-button-toggle group in reactive from makes other controls disappear?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a built a basic reactive form but when with 3 text fields, and a mat-button-toggle.
When I add the toggle (the last form filed in the template below), the regular input form fields become invisible.

Without the toggle, I get this:

[image]

The template and component code are below:

When I add the toggle, I get this:

[image]

```
 <form [formGroup]="bindingAuthorForm" (submit)="submit()">
  <mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Binding Name</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeHolder="1.0.0" formControlName="bindingName" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="bindingAuthorForm.controls['bindingName'].hasError('pattern')">
      <span *ngIf="bindingAuthorForm.controls['bindingName'].errors['required']">This field is
        mandatory.</span>
      <span *ngIf="bindingAuthorForm.controls['bindingName'].errors['pattern']">Lowercase letters, numbers and
        underscore only.</span>
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Version</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeHolder="Version" formControlName="version" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="bindingAuthorForm.controls['version'].hasError('pattern')">
      <span>Version must be Major.Minor.Patch style, e.g. '1.2.3'</span>
    </mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="bindingAuthorForm.controls['version'].hasError('required')">
      <span>Version is required. </span>
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Author</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeHolder="Binding Author" formControlName="authorName" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="bindingAuthorForm.controls['authorName'].hasError('required')">
      <span>Author Name is required. </span>
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  
  When I add the below the fields above disappear:
  <mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="outline">
    <mat-button-toggle-group formControlName="bindingType'">
      <mat-button-toggle value="definitions">Definitions</mat-button-toggle>
      <mat-button-toggle value="entitlements">Entitlements</mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

BindingAuthorComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-binding-author',
  templateUrl: './binding-author.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./binding-author.component.scss']
})
export class BindingAuthorComponent implements OnInit {
  bindingAuthorForm : FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder : FormBuilder  ) {   }
  bindingNameRegex :RegExp =  /^[a-z][a-z0-9_]*$/;
  versionNumberRegex : RegExp = /^\d+.\d+.\d+$/
  public foo : string = "I am foo"

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.bindingAuthorForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      bindingName : [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.bindingNameRegex), Validators.maxLength(9)]],
      version : [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.versionNumberRegex)]],
      authorName : [null, [Validators.required]],
      bindingType : [""]
    })
  }
  submit() {
    if (!this.bindingAuthorForm.valid) {
      return;
    }
    console.log(this.bindingAuthorForm.value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `mat-button-toggle-group` is compatible with the `mat-form-field`. Remove the form field from the button toggle group and you should be fine.

Comment: The overview on the material website says "<mat-button-toggle-group> is compatible with @angular/forms and supports both FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule."  but maybe that will be the easiest way.

Comment: Indeed, it is compatible with the `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` in the sense that it implements the `ControlValueAccessor` interface, but in order to put it in a `mat-form-field` it also needs to implement the `MatFormFieldControl<T>` interface as well. Have a look at [MatSelect for example](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/69598f113be73a29a9216e1b8280158041fe823e/src/material/select/select.ts#L226). This one also implements MatFormFieldControl.